# Where can I find recordings of previous Catalyst town halls?

Tags: catalyst

I wish to view a recent Catalyst town hall broadcast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [user page of IOHK on Crowdcast](https://www.crowdcast.io/iohk) has all the recent town halls in chronological order.  The recordings have their presentation slides and the questions (asked and answered) included in the player.

The recordings on [IOHK's YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnPTB0CuBOByRhpTUdALq4J89m_h7QqLk) only has the video stream available.